# Timber rest api 404

Tags: rest, api, timber

I have installed WP 4.9.5 using nginx and the following plugins: Gravity Forms (v2.3.1) by rocketgenius Advanced Custom Fields PRO (v5.6.10) by Elliot Condon Timber (v1.7.0) by Jared Novack + Upstatement WooCommerce Additional Variation Images (v1.7.12) by WooCommerce WooCommerce (v3.3.5) by Automattic

For some reason i cannot understand REST api calls are not working and return 404 error. Permalinks are enabled! I am trying the simplest GET without requiring authentication

http://domain.test/wp-json/wc/v2/

any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Change link from /wp-json/**wc**/v2/ to /wp-json/**wp**/v2/:

For testing purposes you can use: https://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/
I suggest you to read [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/).
Have a nice day.